# Compare Pandas Object with a String and Print matching word

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare a Pandas Object with a String and I would like to Print out the matching word, but it doesn't work. I hope someone can give me an advice.

My Pandas Object looks like this:

```
  states
0 Bavaria
1 Saarland
2 Berlin
....
```

I tried following Code:

```
print("Match: " + str(german_states[german_states['states'].str.match('12345, Munich, Bavaria')]))
```

and I get following Output:

```
Match: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [states]
Index: []
```

The other point is, I would like to get just the matching String, to continue working with the output. I tried to index the pandas file but then the Code doesnt work.

Comment: I think you need to use `isin()`. Try: `german_states[german_states['states'].isin(['12345, Munich, Bavaria'])]`

Comment: You can use match but you need a regex expression. Besides that it is more valuable to share a valid dataset that we can test.

Comment: isin() doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, even if I think, its not the nicest one:

```
keyword_list = german_states['states'].tolist()

stringInfo= 'Munich, Bavaria, 1234'
test = re.sub(',','',stringInfo)

if set(keyword_list).intersection(test.split()):
   print set(keyword_list).intersection(test.split())
else: 
   print "nothing found"
```

my result:

```
set(['Bavaria'])
```